# VBS- Rename Files With New Names in Loop

Tags: vbscript

I have this script below which renames the files in a folder to a name I want if the original filename contains a partial string match.

The issue is, there's currently 17 files that need to be renamed and I use the same `if statement` 17 times to check for the file name match. I am looking to have only one if statement that is looped through all the files.

Here is the code - **The file names in the code provided below are NOT the actual filenames I use**:

```
Dim fso, folder, file
Dim folderName, searchFileName, renameFile1, renameFile2, renameFile3, renameFile4, renameFile5, renameFile6, renameFile7, renameFile8

' Parameters
'Path
folderName     = "X:\Test\3rd Party"

'Future FileName
renameFile1   = "Mine.xlsx"
renameFile2   = "Yours.xlsx"
renameFile3   = "His.xlsx"
renameFile4   = "Hers.xlsx"
renameFile5   = "Theirs.xlsx"
renameFile6   = "Ours.xlsx"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
For each file In folder.Files    

    ' See if the file starts with the name we search
    if instr (file.Name, "MyFile") then
        file.name = renameFile1
    End If

    if instr (file.Name, "YourFile") then
        file.name = renameFile2
    End If

    if instr (file.Name, "His") then
        file.name = renameFile3
    End If

    if instr (file.Name, "Hers") then
        file.name = renameFile4
    End If

    if instr (file.Name, "TheirFile") then
        file.name = renameFile5
    End If

    if instr (file.Name, "OurFile") then
        file.name = renameFile6
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here:

[Rename Many Files With Specific Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150021/rename-many-files-with-specific-names)

**Code:**

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "MyFile", "Mine.xlsx"
dict.Add "YourFile", "Yours.xlsx"
dict.Add "His", "His.xlsx"
...

For Each file In folder.Files
    For Each str In dict.Keys
        If InStr(str, file.Name) > 0 Then
            file.Name = dict(str)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) to check and get the desired pattern

**Sample script**

```
Dim fso, folder, file, folderName
Dim objRegEx, objMatch

'Path
folderName = "X:\Test\3rd Party"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

' To Regex check if the file name begins with a number
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRegEx
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^[0-9]+" 'if file name begins with a number
End With

' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
For Each file In folder.Files
    'Check if file name begins with number - if yes then rename the file
    Set objMatch = objRegEx.Execute(file.Name)
    If objMatch.Count = 1 Then file.Name = "Name" & objMatch.Item(0).Value & ".xlsx"
    Set objMatch = Nothing
Next
```

I've assumed that you only want to replace the file names which begins with a number and you want to name them in *NameNumber* pattern. You can modify the script to suit your needs.

**Update Sample Script**

```
Dim fso, folder, file, folderName, dict

'Path
folderName = "X:\Test\3rd Party"

'Future FileName
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "MyFile.xlsx", "Mine.xlsx"
dict.Add "YourFile.xlsx", "Yours.xlsx"
dict.Add "HisFile.xlsx", "His.xlsx"
dict.Add "HersFile.xlsx", "Hers.xlsx"
dict.Add "TheirFile.xlsx", "Theirs.xlsx"
dict.Add "OurFile.xlsx", "Ours.xlsx"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
For Each file In folder.Files
    If dict.Exists(file.Name) Then file.Name = dict(file.Name)
Next
```

Based on the new filename information, I have used a dictionary to find a file and rename it based on the information in dictionary. Note that since you are not changing the names of His and Her files, you don't really need to worry about them. For my script, I just imagined the files names as HisFile and HersFile for ease.

Comment: I apologize, I used bad naming conventions for the sake of the post. I have updated the original post, could you perhaps review it and possibly adjust your sample code please? There's no numbers in the actual file names, I simply made use of numbers to not use the original filenames and thought it was the simplest way to explain my situation.

Comment: No worries. Are all these .xlsx files?

Comment: Thank you.. Yes they are all xlsx files

Comment: Added the new script - you can tackle such issues in a number of way. I just gave you a sample where you are just renaming a few files. If you want to rename lots of file, then I would suggest you store the names in a text file and then read the data and use it to rename so that you don't have to hardcode the dictionary items.

Comment: Thank you again for the reply @Pankaj. I ran your script but it isnt renaming the files. There's no error popping up or anything, just not renaming the files.

Comment: I tested the script and it works on my machine and file paths. Check if you are using correct old names and folder path

Comment: I realize now that your script is looking for exact file names.. My original script is looking at partial string matches. Is it possible to amend your script to include the Instr() function perhaps?