# VBS - Rename Many Files With Specific Names

Tags: vbscript

I posted originally here:

[Rename Files With New Names in Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750186/vbs-rename-files-with-new-names-in-loop)

Someone provided a solution which is great:

```
Dim fso, folder, file, folderName, dict

'Path
folderName = "X:\Test\3rd Party"

'Future FileName
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "MyFile.xlsx", "Mine.xlsx"
dict.Add "YourFile.xlsx", "Yours.xlsx"
dict.Add "HisFile.xlsx", "His.xlsx"
dict.Add "HersFile.xlsx", "Hers.xlsx"
dict.Add "TheirFile.xlsx", "Theirs.xlsx"
dict.Add "OurFile.xlsx", "Ours.xlsx"

' Create filesystem object and the folder object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  

' Loop over all files in the folder until the searchFileName is found
For Each file In folder.Files
    If dict.Exists(file.Name) Then file.Name = dict(file.Name)
Next
```

But the only issue is that is looks for exact file name match. My original post included like 17 if statements within a loop and each if statement used the `InStr` function to look for partial string match.

The solution above is much cleaner though, so any help with it would be great.

Perhaps just wondering if there is actually a better way of doing what I want too. For example, once a file is renamed, it's excluded from the next loop through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the partial strings to the filenames in your dictionary

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "MyFile", "Mine.xlsx"
dict.Add "YourFile", "Yours.xlsx"
dict.Add "His", "His.xlsx"
...
```

and add a nested loop where you iterate over the partial filenames and check them against the current filename:

```
For Each file In folder.Files
    For Each str In dict.Keys
        If InStr(str, file.Name) > 0 Then
            file.Name = dict(str)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: You sir are a genius :)